# Arduino infiniti tone

Tags: arduino

I am making a smoke detector.
When it detects smoke iz should alert with buzzer.
Is there any way I could make it to buzz forever until external interupt such as restart pin?
Or could I just remove timing from tone() function.
Here is the code I use.

```
int sensorValue;

int digitalValue;
int green = 8;
int red = 7;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode( 0, INPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);


}

void start(){
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
}

void loop() {

sensorValue = analogRead(0);       
digitalValue = digitalRead(0); 

Serial.println(sensorValue,DEC);  
Serial.println(digitalValue,DEC);

delay(2000);                    
  if(analogRead(0) < 100){
    tone(9,200,1000);
    digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing a sound "forever" is straightforward:

```
if(analogRead(A0) < 100 ) {
  tone(9,2000); // once triggered, will play the sound forever
}
```

To switch it off, you seem to like the RESET button. So there's no need to ever call

```
noTone(9);
```

BTW: what about reading the [reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/) ?

Comment: From https://github.com/bhagman/Tone#ugly-details - duration is optional. If duration is not given, tone will play continuously until stop() is called.

Comment: Yes, but that's not "ugly-details". The official arduino reference is at https://www.arduino.cc/reference. And you are not using the github.com/bhagman library in the code we're talking about.

Comment: The [Tone Ref page](http://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/) refers you to [Bhagman](http://github.com/bhagman/Tone). The official reference gives no details on what happens if the duration is not present. The official Arduino Tone library is based on this tone library. The Ugly details reference should not have been included in my link since it get you to the wrong part of the document. Rather use this: https://github.com/bhagman/Tone#methods

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of ways:

Change your logic that activate the buzzer.

```
while (analogRead(0) < 100){
  tone(9,200,1000);
}
```

Just use an infinite loop:

```
while (1) {
  tone(9,200,1000);
}
```

Reset the Arduino to get out of the infinite loop.

An variation on this would be to replace `(1)` with the code that checks a pin to exit the loop or reads the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

if you're really bent on using interrupts
you didn't  specify what board you're working with but 
for uno the 2 3 pins can be attached as interrupts and just trigger a function that turns off the tone
check out this:
[attachinterrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)